# Alone, I am a group of three

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> Alone, I am a group of three.
>
> When the leader becomes the trailer then I just did me.
>
> Then reverse, turn back, I'm seven of twelve times two,
>
> The one that's last to first is drunk second most by you.
>
> If you've found me, don't yet brag or boast,
>
> To finish, you must find where I'm found first, second, and third most.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Alone, I am a group of three.*

> EAT is a group of three letters.

*When the leader becomes the trailer then I just did me*

> ATE is the past tense of eat.

*Then reverse, turn back, I'm seven of twelve times two*

> ETA is the 7th of the 24-letter Greek alphabet.

*The one that's last to first is drunk second most by you*

> The alphabetically last letter T first, gives TEA, the second most consumed drink after water.

*To finish, you must find where I'm found first, second, and third most.*

> These letters are the [most common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)  in the English language, in order: E, T, A

Comment: You've got everything right except the last part- think about the individual parts of the word

Comment: It should be one specific thing.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu - Ah, that's much better wordplay rather than my statistics.